# How to parse HEX Numbers in Bison

Tags: c, compilation, bison, flex-lexer

I have this project where I'm suppose to work on and my first task is to build a deskCalculator. I want the calculator to be able to parse HEX numbers. Below is the section having the problem.

```
| HEX {$$ = strtol((char *)$1 , (char **)'\n', 16); }
```

A token HEX have been defined above and in the lex file the regular expresion have been defined as

```
hex  [a-f0-9]+
```

The problem is at the level of the strtol function. Please Help me.
Thanks.

Comment: What is `(char **)'\n'` supposed to mean?

Comment: (char **)'\n' as per my idea was to cast the end value to be a new line, because the compiler was complaining

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good reason the compiler was complaining, and a cast is almost never the right answer.

`strtol` stores a pointer to the first character after the converted string into the `end` parameter. Because `10` (the value of `'\n'`) is probably not a valid address for you the program results in undefined behaviour when `strtol` tries to modify it. If you're not interested in the rest of the string you can pass `NULL`:

```
| HEX {$$ = strtol((char *)$1 , NULL, 16); }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to, as soon as lex has seen the hex number, you let lex transform it into a hex value that you pass as the token value. I am not in the specifics of the bison lexer, but the basic code would be:

```
int lexval= 0;
char *c= yytext;
yytext[yyleng]= '\0;
while (*c) {
    lexval = lexval * 16 + (*c<=9 ? *c-'0' : tolower(*c)-'a');
    c++;
}
return(lexval);
```